# $\sqrt[3]{10-x}+\sqrt[3]{30-x}=\sqrt[3]{15-x}+\sqrt[3]{25-x}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, systems-of-equations, elementary-functions

I just happened to find a problem and an elegant solution.

The question asks us to solve the following equation

$$\sqrt[3]{10-x}+\sqrt[3]{30-x}=\sqrt[3]{15-x}+\sqrt[3]{25-x}$$

I am answering this question below but I would love if you can also share a different solution.

P.S: I composed this problem by myself. I do not know if this problem is available anywhere. I would love to get some feedback about the same. It motivates me to create problems and discuss with others.

Comment: $x=20$ works, both sides zero

Comment: definitely, but one is interested in all the solutions!

Comment: $x = 20$ seems to be the only real solution

Comment: Sure. I like to encourage the students to check the easiest possibilities, as a useful habit

Comment: @kodwx, Yes. I have posted the solution as well.

Comment: Denote by $x_1,x_2$ the two terms on the L.H.S. ordered so that $x_1<x_2$. Then $x_1+x_2$ is "your common $A$", and $40=x_1^3+x_2^3=(x_1+x_2)((x_1+x_2)^2 - 3x_1x_2)$, which determines also the product, when $A$ is fixed. By Vieta, $x_1,x_2$ are determined under the given order. Now the two terms $x_1'<x_2'$ on the R.H.S. also satisfy the same equations, so we must have $x_1=x_1'$ and $x_2=x_2'$.

Comment: Just as a matter of putting things symmetrically - so that the solver feels better, and does not consider the problem ugly if the idea comes to her / him in between - just substitute $y=20-x$ and ask for a solution for the equivalent equation:$$\sqrt[3]{y-10} + \sqrt[3]{y+10} = \sqrt[3]{y-5} + \sqrt[3]{y+5}\ .$$

Comment: I'm not understanding the $x=20$ comments. Is this a complex valued problem? Because $(-10)^{1/3}$ is not a real number. It is not defined in the reals.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: I am pretty sure that in this context, $t \mapsto t^{1/3}$ is understood as the inverse function of $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, t \mapsto t^3$, and that is defined for all real numbers.

Comment: ... well the problem should maybe state that $x$ is real, or make clear which branch of the  function y\to y^{1/3}$ is involved when also complex numbers may appear.

Comment: @MartinR maybe, although I rarely see it defined like that.

Comment: @dan_fulea, Right, It makes it look easier but eventually one has to proceed the way it is done in the solution below.

Comment: @dan_fulea Your reasoning is incorrect. Check lab_bhattacharjee's answers and the comments. You cannot conclude $x_1={x_1}^'$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $$A=\sqrt[3]{10-x}+\sqrt[3]{30-x}=\sqrt[3]{15-x}+\sqrt[3]{25-x}$$

I will use the following

\begin{align}
A^3=&(p+q)^3 \\
 =&p^3+q^3+3pq(p+q) \\
=&p^3+q^3+3pq(A)
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
A^3=&(10-x)+(30-x)+3(\sqrt[3]{10-x})(\sqrt[3]{30-x})(A) \\
=&(40-2x)+3(\sqrt[3]{10-x})(\sqrt[3]{30-x})(A) 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
A^3=&(15-x)+(25-x)+3(\sqrt[3]{15-x})(\sqrt[3]{25-x})(A) \\
=&(40-2x)+3(\sqrt[3]{15-x})(\sqrt[3]{25-x})(A) 
\end{align}

and hence we have
$$(\sqrt[3]{10-x})(\sqrt[3]{30-x})(A)=(\sqrt[3]{15-x})(\sqrt[3]{25-x})(A)$$

which is impossible unless $A=0$

Hence $$A=\sqrt[3]{10-x}+\sqrt[3]{30-x}=0$$ and

I conclude $x=20$

Comment: EQs 6 and 8 should both have $(40-2x) + ...$

Comment: @user121330 corrected, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sqrt[3]{10-x}=a,\sqrt[3]{30-x}=b,\sqrt[3]{15-x}=c, \sqrt[3]{25-x}=d$

We have $a+b=c+d\ \ \ \ (1)$

Again $a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3$

$\iff(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)=(c+d)^3-3cd(c+d)$

So, either **case**$\#1: a+b=0$

or **case**$\#2:ab=cd$

in that case, $(a,b); (c,d)$ are the roots of the same quadratic equation

$\implies$ either $a=c, b=d$ or $a=d,b=c$

Can you take it from here?

Btw, thanks for posting the nice problem !

Comment: It's not necessarily true that $ab=cd$. That's because $a+b=c+d=0$ is also possible.

Comment: @permutation_matrix, thanks

Comment: @permutation_matrix, What if $a+b\ne0?$

Comment: $ab=cd$ is impossible because $c^3d^3-a^3b^3=75$

Comment: @permutation_matrix, $$ab=cd$$  is coming in general from $$a+b=c+d, a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3$$. But $ab=cd$ is nullified by their current values